# copy related file with apache camel

Tags: apache-camel

First of all: i'm a camel newbie :-)

I want to watch a directory for xml files, then i want to move that xml file to another directory and move a pdf file with the same filename (but other extention) to the same directory, and then do some java stuff.

What is the best way to move that pdf file?

This is the route that i currently have:

```
from("file://C:/temp/camel/in?delete=true").filter(new Predicate() {

        @Override
    public boolean matches(final Exchange exchange) {
                String filename = (String) exchange.getIn().getHeader("CamelFileRelativePath");
        return "xml".equals(FilenameUtils.getExtension(filename));
    }
})
.to("file://C:/temp/camel/out").bean(ServiceBean.class, "callWebservice")
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing you want to ignore any files that are not xml / pdf?

Comment: I want to watch a directory for only xml files. I have done this this way: `from(file://C:/temp/camel/in?move=/temp/camel/out&moveFailed=/temp/camel/error&include=.*\\.xml&delay=10000)`. I need that xml file because i need to send it to a webservice. In that same from directory, there is a pdf file related to the xml file. with the same filename but with a pdf extention. I want to copy that pdf file to the same output directory when i receive a xml file. At the moment i have done this with java code: `from(...).bean(FileService.class, "movePdfToOut").bean(WebServiceBean.class, "call")`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that without using a filter but a regular expression to filter only the 2 extensions, .xml and .pdf

```
from("file://C:/temp/camel/in?delete=true&?include=.*.xml|.*.zip")                      
    .to("file://C:/temp/camel/out").bean(ServiceBean.class, "callWebservice");
```

If you use filter it will delete the files that you are not interested in, which might not be what you want, this solution will just leave them in that directory